# SQL Server 2008 update query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I need to update `image_id` in the `user_group` table with the value of `image_id2` in `view_kantech_images` where the names match.

My query is returning an error:

```
update user_group
set image_id = (select vkm.image_id2 
                from view_kantech_matched as vkm 
                where vkm.name like user_group.name)
where name = view_kantech_matched.name
```

The error that it returns is:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "view_kantech_matched.name" could not be bound.

Comment: what is the error that it returns?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "view_kantech_matched.name" could not be bound.

Comment: Can someone please explain why I recieved a downvote on this? As i included my query in my question, so I didn't think it showed a lack of research effort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the update-join syntax instead:

```
UPDATE ug
SET    ug.image_id = vkm.image_id2
FROM   user_group ug
JOIN   view_kantech_matched vkm  ON vkm.name = ug.name
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
UPDATE
    im
SET
    im.image_id  = image_id2
FROM
    user_group im
    JOIN
    view_kantech_matched gm ON im.name = gm.name
```

Comment: It was right, but i've already marked Mureinik as having the right answer. I will up vote you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update column with a recordset if your subquery returns more than one row, which is not possible in SQL Server. Try to make inline table which is in subquery as suggested by Murenik

Answer (score 0):

Errr, yeah... you can't do this.

You need to make sure that the sub-query in your UPDATE...

```
select vkm.image_id2 
from view_kantech_matched as vkm 
where vkm.name like user_group.name
```

... could be run independently.  You can't use `user_group.name` in the subquery... SQL Server doesn't know what it is (yet).

And then your "outer query" attempts to use a `WHERE` clause linking back to "`view_kantech_matched`" in the inner query.  You can't do this !!

```
update user_group
set image_id = 
( ...)
where name = view_kantech_matched.name
```

I agree with Mureinik's method.

You need to get rid of the subquery, and do the `join` within the `update`.